# load disqus comments on single pages based on the scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, disqus

I have applied disqus comments on my single blog page which consists of many posts on one page.

```
<div>
     <article class='post hentry' expr:data-id='data:post.id' expr:data-url='data:post.url'>
    .............
    </article>
    <div class='showDisqus' data-title='MyTitle' expr:data-id='data:post.id' expr:data-url='data:post.url'>Show Comments</div>
</div>

<div>  
     <article class='post hentry' expr:data-id='data:post.id' expr:data-url='data:post.url'>
    .............
    </article>
    <div class='showDisqus' data-title='MyTitle' expr:data-id='data:post.id' expr:data-url='data:post.url'>Show Comments</div>
</div>

<div>
   <article class='post hentry' expr:data-id='data:post.id' expr:data-url='data:post.url'>
    .............
    </article>
    <div class='showDisqus' data-title='MyTitle' expr:data-id='data:post.id' expr:data-url='data:post.url'>Show Comments</div>
</div>
```

The following code I use.

```
$('.showDisqus').on('click', function(){   // click event of the show comments button
    var this_ = $(this);
        disqus_shortname = 'example',
        title = $(this).attr('data-title'),
        identifier = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-id')),
        url = $(this).attr('data-url');

    if (window.DISQUS) {

        DISQUS.reset({ // Remove the old call
          reload: false,
          config: function () {
          this.page.identifier = window.old_identifier;
          this.page.url = window.old_url;
          this.page.title = window.old_title;
          }
        });
        $('.showDisqus').show();
        $('#disqus_thread').remove();

        $('<div id="disqus_thread"></div>').insertAfter(this_);

        setTimeout( function() { // Creates a new call DISQUS, with the new ID
            DISQUS.reset({
              reload: true,
              config: function () {
              this.page.identifier = identifier;
              this.page.url = url;
              this.page.title = title;
              }
            });
            window.old_identifier = identifier;
            window.old_url = url;
            window.old_title = title;
        });

    } else {

        var disqus_identifier = parseFloat(identifier),
            disqus_title = title,
            disqus_url = url;

        $('<div id="disqus_thread"></div>').insertAfter(this_);

        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();

        setTimeout( function() { // Sorry, there must be a better way to force the ID called correctly
            DISQUS.reset({
              reload: true,
              config: function () {
              this.page.identifier = identifier;
              this.page.url = url;
              this.page.title = title;
              }
            });
        },500);

        window.old_identifier = identifier;
        window.old_url = url;
        window.old_title = title;

    }
    $(this).fadeOut();  // remove the show comments button
});
```

disqus comments will appear below the post by clicking the button, but I want something more simple, so disqus comments will appear automatically when the visitor scrolls the screen to the bottom of the post. How can i do it?

Comment: Since you can load only one Disqus, than what comments to show if there are 2, 3 articles visible on screen? If you auto-load first or last, than there may be the issue, some comments would never be loaded.

Comment: @skobaljic what if when the user scrolls the first article then disqus comments for the first article will be displayed, and when scrolled to the second article disqus comments for the second article will be displayed and automatically delete the disqus comment for the first article, and so on  $('#disqus_thread').remove();

Comment: Was this problem solved? Looks like I also need a solution.